# Media & Plugin screens stall

Tags: theme-development

I'm building out a theme and at some point the Media Upload & Plugin Search functions broke. They are seemingly disparate but they broke at the same time and the way they broke seems connected.

I can't trace when or how they broke and I can't find any issues anywhere that quite match the problem.

1. I'm able to upload media via the "Add New Media" but the media name switches to `` `2544 `` after the upload completes and the progress bar hangs on "Crunching..." If I check the media library, the image is there.
2. When in an existing post, I attempt to change the picture by clicking the picture and it will take me to the media library modal but there will be a single empty image container and the spinner will spin but the screen hangs. So I can't change any images.
3. When in an existing post, I attempt to remove the image by clicking "Remove Featured Image" but nothing happens. At all.
4. Plugins - When I go to "Add New" plugin, the screen loads normally with featured plugins. However when I search for a plugin, I get the expected spinner but plugins never load.

These 4 problems seem to be connected somehow but I can't find where in my theme there could be a connection. I've disabled all of the plugins but that didn't affect any change. I changed the theme to 2017 and that fixed the problem.

My question is, what function or filter or hook could connect these? I'd share code but... short of sharing a full repo, I'm not sure what to share or where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

One of my co-workers was working on a different file for me and he found the issue.

there was a `` ` `` at the begining of the functions file.
So the functions.php file started:
`` `<?php ``

Which is why, I assume, I was getting an error on media that looked like it did.

Hope this helps someone because I was up against a wall.